# How to initialize struct[] or make an alias or make a pointer to existing struct[] in C++

Tags: c++, struct

I am adjusting existing code and want to avoid renaming variables, etc. I have defined value in one struct[] and want to assign its value to another struct[].

Simplified example. I have:

```
static const struct {
  int xyz;
} var1[] = { {1}, {2}, {3} };
```

And what I want to do would look somewhat like this:

```
static const struct {
  int xyz;
} var2[] = var1;

[...]

if (var2[1].xyz === 1) {
  [...]
}
```

Basically I need to alias/point to/copy struct[] using another struct[].

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't assign arrays or uses arrays as initializers in C++.

Comment: Initialization lists have to be literal lists.

Comment: Use std::array instead of mundane arrays.

Comment: You can make a pointer with: `static const struct {
  int xyz;
} *var2 = var1`;

Comment: BTW, why haven't you given a name to the struct, so you don't have to repeat all the members?

Comment: If I can not initialize, can I somehow specify variable to be a pointer to existing value?

Comment: I tried this: `static const struct {
  int xyz;
} var1[] = { {1}, {2}, {3} };

static const struct { int xyz; } *var2 = var1;` but got error `error: cannot convert ‘const<anonymous struct>*’ to ‘const<anonymous struct>*’ in initialization
 static const struct { int xyz; } *var2 = var1;`

Comment: With: `static const struct {
  int xyz;
} var1[] = { {1}, {2}, {3} };

static const struct { int xyz; } *var2[] = var1;` I am getting: `error: initializer fails to determine size of ‘var2’
 static const struct { int xyz; } *var2[] = var1;`

Comment: What do you mean by *point to* using *struct[]*?

Comment: You are using 2 *anonymous* structs. They have different types.  So you can't declare a pointer of one type to point to an instance of the other type.  You need to separate your `struct` declaration from your variable declarations, and give the `struct` a type name. Then you can declare variables of the same type. `struct mystruct { int xyz; };  static const mystruct var1[] = { {1}, {2}, {3} }; static const mystruct *var2 = var1;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, that seems to work! Thank you!

Comment: @RemyLebeau `auto` or `decltype` can be used to make more instances of the same unnamed struct. (It would be a better idea to give it a name though, as you suggest)

Comment: OP it is not clear whether you want 2 separate arrays that both have the same content; or whether you just want 2 different names that refer to the same storage.  If the latter, then the "duplicate" is not actually a duplicate

Comment: @M.M, `auto` is actually is perfect with my use-case! I did not know about such feature in C++ Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt cannot work because 1. Arrays are not assignable, and because 2. your two unnamed classes are separate and unrelated.

> can I somehow specify variable to be a pointer to existing value?

You sure can:

```
static auto var2 = var1;  // pointer to first element
static auto var3 = &var1; // pointer to the array
```

Prior to C++11, you would have to give a name for the class:

```
static const struct i_have_a_name {
  int xyz;
} var1[] = { {1}, {2}, {3} };

static const i_have_a_name *var2 = var1;
static const i_have_a_name (*var3)[3] = &var1;
```

Comment: Also possible is `auto& var4 = var1;` which causes the two names `var4` and `var1` have the same meaning